# Ignore null fields and empty fields/arrays with Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson, annotations, jackson-databind

My project builds on jdk1.6.0_141 and I am currently using jackson 2.7.9.below is the class that use to marshal the object.

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;

@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)
public class Employee{

    private String number;
    private String department;
    private List<Project> projects;

    //getters and setters goes here
}
```

I have added the below dependencies in my pom file

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
     <version>2.7.9</version>
</dependency>       
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.9</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.9</version>
</dependency>
```

I want to remove the null values and empty arrays from my result which is a json string but the null values are not getting removed. I even used

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
```

but the result is still the same. I applied the same for anothe rproject which builds in JDK 8 and the version of jackson is 2.9.2 and in the response, it removes all nulls and emty fields and arrays just by adding NON_EMPTY only.

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)
```

Can someone please guide me the reason why I am not getting the expected results.How can I use the JsonInclude properly to skip all the nulls, empty fields and empty arrays.

This is the method that I invoke to load the json file from the resources folder and parse

```
    InputStream in = getClass().getResourceAsStream(
            "/EmployeeFile.json");
    ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int len;

    while ((len = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        os.write(buffer, 0, len);
    }
    Employee emp = JSONUtil.toObject(os.toByteArray());
```

Object mapper

```
public static Employee toObject(byte[] jsonData) throws IOException {
    Employee emp = null;
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    emp = objectMapper.readValue(jsonData, Employee.class);         
    return emp;
}
```

Comment: Do you use any customisation on `ObjectMapper` level? Do you use any custom serialiser for `Employee` class?

Comment: Apologies for the late reply. My employee class implements Serializable interface. Below is how I use Object mapping. Can it be a reason why I'm not getting the expected result?                                       
 public static Employee toObject(byte[] jsonData) throws IOException {
  Employee emp = null;
  ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
  emp = objectMapper.readValue(jsonData, Employee.class);   
  return emp;
 }

Comment: No, `Serializable` should not be a problem there. Your method `toObject` gets `byte[]` how do you create it? Could you show us how do you invoke this method?

Comment: I have added the code in the question above as an update.

Comment: Thanks for showing this. In question you mentioned that serialisation does not remove `empty`/`null` fields. Could you also show us how do you serialise `Employee` instance to `JSON`?

Comment: I’m using IbjectMapper for this

Comment: Do you mean `ObjectMapper `? So, you use `objectMapper.writeValue` method to serialise `Employee` to `JSON`? Is it true?

Comment: This is what I do in my logic. I need to load a json file from my resources folder and using ObjectMapper.readValue() I convert it to Object. and after some manipulation I have to return this object. I don't need to convert it back to json. I have annotated my classes which constructs the Object (e.g: Employee.java) with @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY) . This is removing all the emty arrays but not null values. This is why I need assistance.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188978/discussion-between-michal-ziober-and-sher17).